# Social Sciences: Screening cost-compliance survey

Tags: clustering, panel-data, ordinal-data

I have a survey in which 500 subjects were asked if they would take a screening test if the cost was free, \$1, \$10, \$50, and \$100.

I have information on subjects'  age, race, etc.

I want to estimate the relationship between cost and probability of reporting refusal of the test. What analysis should I be using?

Can I treat these as 5 independent samples? Should I try mixed levels? What if instead of cost (potentially continuous,  but here ordinal) I wanted evaluate the effect of color or type of test (nominal categories of test)?

Answer (score 2):

I assume respondents were asked for each of the cost estimates you provided whether they would agree to screening. In that case, unless there are missing data, you have a balanced design and need not worry too much about repeated measures.

The Cochran Armitage test-of-trend would be a way to answer the question, "does cost influence risk of not screening?" A logistic regression model treating the ordinal values of cost... or potentially the actual monetary amount... assesses the same thing. You can predict quantiles of screening based on cost, e.g. (we expect 50% of the population will screen if screening costs are reduced/increased to $XX).

The logistic regression model allows you to adjust for other blocking factors and determine the relative impact of other test features, controlling for cost.